# AccessDB. Table. Creation or modification time?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Im creating a Stored Procedure on an 2008 SQL server.

I cant find how to retrieve the creation date of a given table in MS Access using SQL (or C# since it will be running inside a SSIS)

Besides the creation data, the time it was last modified would be also needed.

Any help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can access this through the DAO interop assembly: http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-277518.html

Comment: If by last modified, you mean data changed or added, this is not available unless you have included a suitable field (column).

Comment: thanks a lot, checking right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might depend on the exact version of Access that created the database, but this information is  found in the `MSysObjects` table (Access 97-2010)

Comment: The creation date can be unreliable. MSysObjects is generally not available outside MS Access.

Comment: great! gonna import that table and comparate the dates to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @Remou do you know of something completely reliable? Thanks.

Comment: I would be a little wary if you are using these dates for comparison purposes.

Comment: The access tables, after creation time, work for over one hour. So all I need to know if the difference between Creation Date and Getdate() is more than an hour. If so (it doesnt matter if its 65 minutes or 75, no need for extreme accuracy) the process continue.

Comment: @DanielSh. In that case everything should be okay, AFAIK. I was concerned that you might be checking archived files.